# How do you calculate the number of change points in real data using Ruptures?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to use the ruptures python change point detection library.  I can't see how to get the number of change points in a real world signal.  All the examples seem to start with experimental data for which the number of change points are known.

I can feed my data into algorithms and find the change points for a fixed number of change points.   But I can't work out how to detect the number of breakpoints.

```
import numpy as np
import ruptures as rp

# values is real world time series data from graylog histo.
signal = np.array(values)

c = rpt.costs.CostL1().fit(signal)
model = "l2" 
algo = rpt.Pelt(model=model, custom_cost=c)
algo = algo.fit(signal)
bkps = algo.predict(pen=300000)
rpt.display(signal, bkps, bkps, figsize=(20, 12))
```

I've tried various combinations of different algorithms, cost functions etc.  I'm looking to have something that is hands-off, i.e. not manually tuned all the time.  In this example the choice of pen seems to determine the number of change points.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I've modified the question to include what I've done so far.

Comment: @Since the `ruptures` isn't complete project, and I suggest you shouldn't choose it right now. try to implement yourself. you can try to use some `pandas` function, i.e `Series.pct_change` .

Comment: Thanks Frank.  Yeah I'd considered something like that.  Pick 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 etc change points and try and work out which one has the least error maybe.   I was hoping to avoid doing it myself when there's probably a lot of research out there on methods to do this (that I don't want to have to read :).